# Did PlayFramework's managed view package structure change?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I just dug out a rather old (2.0 or so) PlayFramework project of mine realizing that plenty of my views are broken after I updated to 2.1.3.

I'm not entirely sure if this is an actual Play issue or a misconfiguration on my part, since I don't find any hints in Play's changelogs.

If I recall it right the views have previously been managed in packages such as

`main.views.html.my_root_view.template.scala`
`main.views.html.subpackage.my_subpacke_view.template.scala`

whereas they are now packaged like

`main.views.html.my_root_view.template.scala`
`main.views.subpackage.html.my_subpacke_view.template.scala`
`main.views.subpackage.subsubpackage.html.my_subsubpacke_view.template.scala`

Thus calling `@subpackage.my_subpacke_view()` from `my_root_view` now fails and has to be changed to `@views.subpackage.html.my_subpacke_view()` which is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was a result of me renaming the `app/views` folder to `app/view`. It works the way it should if you leave the folder names the way they are.

Further reading: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/SxZgeT6mIDQ